# Sending select form "selected detail" by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created a form with a select drop-down list that effect the other one. I mean, the choice in the first drop-down list effect the data in the other drop-down list. I did it using Json and jQuery.

The problem is that I can not get the dorm details by email. it doesn't work.

The json file is:

```
{
"health":[
    ["1","Biorgonomi"],
    ["2","Diet and Weight Loss"],
    ["3","Lasik"],
    ["4","Smoking Cessation"],
    ["5","Body Lines"],
    ["6","Treatment of hemorrhoids"],
    ["7","Treatment of snoring"],
    ["8","personal trainer"],
    ["9","Gyms"],
    ["10","hearing aid"],
    ["11","Nail Fungus"],
    ["12","Pilates"]
],
"mercedes":[
    ["13","class A"],
    ["14","class B"],
    ["15","class C"],
    ["16","class E"]
],
"audi":[
    ["17","a3"],
    ["18","a4"],
    ["19","a5"],
    ["20","a6"]
],
"volswagen":[
    ["21","polo"],
    ["22","golf"],
    ["23","cady"]
]
}
```

The jQuery file is:

```
jQuery().ready(function(){
var tabMarque=[];
$.getJSON('http://thewebsite.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/js/healthandbeauty/healthandbeautydetails.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
         tabMarque[index]=val;
    });
});

$('#Marque').change(function(event) {
    $marque=$(this).val();
    $htmlOption='<option value="0">Choix du serie</option>';
    if($marque!=0)
    {
        $.each(tabMarque[$marque], function(key, value) {
             $htmlOption+='<option value="'+value[0]+'">'+value[1]+'</option>';
        });
    }
    $('#Serie').html($htmlOption);
});
});
```

The html form :

```
<form action="http://thewebsite.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/js/healthandbeauty/js/send_to_email.php" method="get">
    <select id="Marque">
                <option value="0">CAR COMPANY</option>
                <option value="health">health</option>
                <option value="mercedes">mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">audi</option>
                <option value="volswagen">volswagen</option>
            </select>
            <select id="Serie"></select>

<select id="Location">
                <option value="0">Your Location</option>
                <option value="Elondon">East London</option>
                <option value="nlondon">North London</option>
                <option value="wlondon">West London</option>
                <option value="slondon">South London</option>
            </select>
<input name="vemail" placeholder="Your Email" type="text" value="">
<input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

The php file that send the details to my email :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
// Checking For Blank Fields..
if($_POST["Marque"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["Serie"]==""||$_POST["Location"]==""){
echo "Fill All Fields..";
}else{
// Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
$email=$_POST['vemail'];
// Sanitize E-mail Address
$email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
// Validate E-mail Address
$email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email){
echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
}
else{
$subject = $_POST['Marque'];
$message = $_POST['Serie'];
$location= $_POST['Location'];
$headers = 'From:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$headers .= 'Cc:'. $email2 . "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
// Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
mail("myemail@xyz.com", $subject, $message, $headers, $location);
echo "Your mail has been sent successfuly ! Thank you for your feedback";
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: One of the main issues appears to be that you haven't set a `name` attribute on your `select` inputs.

Comment: i need to change it instead of the ID?

Comment: Some of your code relies on those IDs afaics, so just add name attributes with the same values as the IDs.

Comment: hey, i did that. its not working. after submit the form i get white page. the url is ...send_to_email.php?Marque=health&Serie=7&Location=Elondon&vemail=r.regev%40hotmail.com&submit=Send

Comment: Check your error logs to find out what's wrong, or enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: sorry but how to enable error reporting?